# how can I upload a gzipped json file to bigquery via the HTTP API?

Tags: google-bigquery

When I try to upload an uncompressed json file, it works fine; but when I try a gzipped version of the same json file, the job would fail with lexical error resulted from failure to parse the json content.

I gzipped the json file with the gzip command from Mac OSX 10.8 and I have set the sourceFormat to: "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON".

Did I do something incorrectly or gzipped json file should be processed differently?

Comment: How are you uploading the compressed file? Are you using a multipart mime request, or are you using a resumable upload? Are you using the Java/Python client library? Do you have a job id of the failed load job?

Comment: I am uploading the file using multiplart/related HTTP request and not resumable. The compressed file fails but plain old JSON works

Answer (score 2):

I believe that using the multipart/related request it is not possible to submit binary data (such as the compressed file. However, if you don't want to use uncompressed data, you may be able to use resumable upload.

What language are you coding in? The python jobs.insert() [api](https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/bigquery_v2.jobs.html#insert) takes a media upload parameter, which you should be able to give a filename to in order to do resumable upload (which sends your job metadata and new table data as separate streams). I was able to use this to upload a compressed file.

This is what bq.py uses, so you could look at the source code [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-tools/source/browse/#git/bq).

If you aren't using python, the googleapis client libraries for other languages should have similar functionality.

Comment: I am writing in nodejs. I wasn't able to find any bigquery specific examples in nodejs at all, which is way I am using the HTTP API. Can you point me to a nodejs client library example on bigquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload gzipped files to Google Cloud Storage, and BigQuery will be able to ingest it with a load job:

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery#loaddatagcs